# PARSER - Nosuchfield error while loading data froom hdfs in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to run the following code. It looks like a dependency issue to me mostly.

```
    Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().parquet("hdfs://localhost:9000/test/arxiv.parquet");
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PARSER
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufHelper.getRemoteException(ProtobufHelper.java:71)
```

I have added dependency of apache hadoop common.
Can someone point out possible problem with the code ?

Answer (score 0):

First post, I don't know if I'm doing this right, though had the same problem, and I added a bunch of dependencies till it solves the problem. I'll give you the list I don't really know which ones are really needed :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-hadoop" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-avro" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-encoding" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-column" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-common" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" %% "parquet-scala" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.parquet" % "parquet-hadoop-bundle" % "1.11.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "3.3.1" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer given by MinoS03 the required dependencies are the following:

- hadoop-common
- hadoop-hdfs-client